# How to create legend to a scatter plot with scaled points: [R]

Tags: r, plot

I have created a scatter plot with circle size changing with the intensity of the data: Fro 0 to 2, from 2 to 4,.. from 8 to 10. Does anyone could help me to create the proper legend for my plot?.

My code is:

```
require(xlsx)     

data <- read.xlsx("data.xlsx", 1, header=TRUE)   # reading the data

BRfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))   # the color gradient

itvl <- c(0,2,4,6,8,10)

plot(data$years, data$cars, cex=findInterval(data$emission, itvl), col="black" )
```

Comment: Have you looked at `legend`?

Comment: If the only thing you're changing is the circle **size**, then your legend is going to be almost indecipherable. The human eye is not that good at referencing diameters (or circumferences) of a bunch of different circles.  If you really need to have an exact relationship between intensity and plot, I recommend using color as well.  Typically, "bubble plots" like this are intended only to show relative magnitudes.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a reproducible data set

```
n <- 50
data <- data.frame(years=1950+(1:n), cars=rnorm(n), emission=runif(n,0,10))
```

Then use your code to plot the figure

```
itvl <- c(0,2,4,6,8,10)
plot(data$years, data$cars, cex=findInterval(data$emission, itvl), col="black" )
```

To be able to create the legend, I've used `legend()` as Marc in the box suggested.

```
legend("topright", legend=itvl, pt.cex=itvl, pch=1)
```

You can use options such as xjust and x.intersp to change the spacing between the symbols and legend. You can use bty to remove the box.